# Viewport controls in UE5 - can you lock the Z axis?

Tags: unreal-5, configuration

I recently got into UE5 after using Unity some years ago - I am a bit surprised about the shooter-like controls in the level editor, as most of the time I will want to pan across the level (X/Y axes) while looking down at the level at an angle. Using the default controls, moving with W will move me straight through the level.

While holding down the LMB, dragging up/down actually does exactly what I would want from the W and S keys - is there any way to configure them to do just that?

Answer (score 0):

For panning, the [docs say](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/viewport-controls-in-unreal-engine/):

> Alt + MMB + Drag
>
> Tracks the camera left, right, up, and down in the direction of mouse movement.

I'm not an UE5 dev so I can't test this solution myself. 
For future reference, Unreal Engine 5 uses Maya style controls - if you have trouble finding navigation / UI info for EU5 directly, try searching for the same thing with Maya instead.